# non-root man pages with Linux-Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, documentation, man

I'm working on a Linux-Ubuntu server as non-root user. I created a small application and because I'm not a privileged user I'm going to install it under $HOME/bin directory (this directory is in the $PATH variable).

I also created a manual page and gzipped it, let's call it **app.1.gz**. Obviously as non-root I can't copy the man page to /usr/share/man/man1, but I want to invoke the page as usual (with the command **man app**. I tried by setting both $MANPATH and $PATH but it doesn't work.

What I have to do to invoke my manual page with **man** command? (obviously without specify the containing directory)

Comment: Setting `$MANPATH` should have worked. Show what you set it to, and where you installed the man pages. Also, make sure you exported the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What did you set MANPATH to?

```
export MANPATH=/home/username/path/to/man
```

works if the directory **/home/username/path/to/man** contains a directory structure that follows the lead of the system, e.g., **./man/man1**, **./man/man8** ... man pages in those directories will be found.  I verified this on a ubuntu 12.04 box.

Comment: Are you telling me that I must write something like this: **export MANPATH=/home/username/application/man/man1** ?

I've tried like that but it doesn't work

Comment: Thanks to your help I think I found out. The directory that contains the manual must be called **man**.